# How to group a set of divs for accessibility

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover

I wanted some help with accessibility: How can we group a set of divs so they are read out as a single group in screen reader mode?

Example:

[image: Sample layout]

Here you can see that there are two rows; how can I make each row be read out with all the details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to set an `aria-label` on the parent div and hide the child divs using `aria-hidden="true"`.

Based on your example image, the `aria-label` would have the format:

`aria-label="<TIME> <DESCRIPTION> <CITY>"`

e.g. `aria-label="10:31am Package left FedEx location Memphis, TN"`

The screen reader should announce the `aria-label` on the parent div and ignore the child divs.

Comment: You can only add `aria-label` to a `div` if there is `role` attribute set, see: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance-naming